# In what directory does the Dolphin HD browser store its files?

Tags: dolphin-browser

I already have root access and tried to use ES File Explorer to search for "dolphin" but to no avail.

Comment: try searching for thunar :) Are you looking for the data files or the download directory?

Comment: Okay I'll try that. I'm looking for the data files. I'm presuming that the download directory is the same as that of the default web browser?

Comment: Hm - just tried that and also tried mobotap (the parent company). neither worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Applications store their data in a folders named after their package. 
These folders are located in `data/data`.

The easiest way to find out the package name is to look at the Play Store url.

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser
```

The package name is the part that comes after `id=`.
You can see that Dolphin's package name is `mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser`, so the full path is:

```
/data/data/mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser
```

Comment: Polished answer... :)

Comment: It would probably be worth also mentioning that the location Dolphin uses for backup files on the sdcard is (sdcardpath)\TunnyBrowser.

Answer (score 4):

`/data/data/mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser`

Answer (score 1):

I found it on the SD card in the folder "tunnybrowser"...